# Should I install jpeg library when I use Generic Image Library in BOOST

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

I have a question related to [Generic Image Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html) in BOOST. At the beginning of using the library, I try to read a jpeg image using the following codes:

```
rgb8_image_t img;
jpeg_read_image("test.jpg",img);
```

However, when I compile the codes, I have the following error:

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'jpeglib.h': No such file or directory
```

I find the jpeglib.h is not a file inside the library, and therefore I think it is mandatory to install the jpeg library when using this library. However, when very little information about it can be found in the Internet. I am now using the library with VC10 in the windows environment, and should I compile the JPEG library before using the Generic Image Library? Furthermore, should I compile the JPEG library statically or dynamically?  Where should I put the library inside the Generic Image Library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your answer can be found [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/gil/doc/html/gildesignguide.html#IO_DG).

It looks like you don't need to compile libjpeg before boost, but you do need to have it available when building code that uses the jpeg I/O functions.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. boost GIL is closely tied to a separate, external library from www.ijg.org (seems like mostly Germans). For Microsoft platforms,
I found there is no installer - you have to compile the source code. And worse
for me, there are some Visual Studio configuration files, but not for v. 8.
So I made my own solution/project from scratch. Don't be alarmed, it's not
so bad. It readily compiles. Briefly, here's how:

[1] download the source code zip file jpegsr9b.zip, from www.ijg.org.

[2] make a simple console-based Visual Studio project ("jconfig") somewhere in the directory where you unpacked the source tree. Add just 1 source code file: ckconfig.c. Compile and run the program. It will make a header file, jconfig.h. Copy or move this file into the main source code directory - there is only 1 directory containing source code in this package.

`[3] make another Visual Studio project that will create the library for the JPG package. Configure the project to make a library (I assume you know how), and include the JPG package source code directory in the "Additional Include Directories" configuration parameter.`

[4] Include all the source code files (they are all .c files), except the following: rdjpgcom.c, wrjpgcom.c, and jpegtran.c. These files are standalone programs (each with main() -obviously you don't want them in a library).

`[5] exclude 2 of the following files (ie, include only 1 of these files): jmemname.c, jmemnobs.c, or jmemansi.c. They contain a different implementations of a "memory manager". I used jmemnobs.c, as the comments indicated it was the simplest implementation, and I just wanted the code to work and was in a hurry. So, in other words, if you did step [4] and included all .c files, now take out 2 of the 3 files listed from your main project file.`

[6] build the library. It is completely standalone, so all the files should compile fine.